# How does wordpress allow posting of code via textarea

Tags: wordpress, post, textarea, lamp

I recently asked a question about LAMP stack not allowing posting of <script> tag via textarea, the request is killed by the apache i guess as the $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST fields are all empty.
I was just wondering how does wordpress allow users to add widgets, updated template files and create pages using a textarea control that allows <script> tag.

**UPDATE**
I've created a pastebin entry for the form here: http://pastebin.com/1Jaz9rRz

Basically it is an auto generated form, I've copy pasted from the source code.

**UPDATE**

I've moved the code for testing to the server here: http://www.007softwares.com/testing.php

The form is being posted to itself, i've echoed the $_REQUEST array to see what was posted. You can see when you just submit the form, fields are visible and when you type script tag the error page appears. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the script tag is really getting removed? How and where exactly do you see it? Are you looking at the output in a browser and not seeing it there?

Comment: The script processing the form does not find anything in the $_POST,$_GET and $_REQUEST arrays, they are totally blank when script tag is placed anywhere inside the textarea. Everything works fine when script tag is not present

Comment: that is indeed weird. Are you 10000% sure mod_security is not installed? What about PHP's Suhosin patch? (You can find out using `phpinfo()`)

Comment: yeah mod_security is not installed, I added the code with <Ifmodule> page and it raised errors. Not sure about Suhosin patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LAMP stack doesn't care what text is submitted via a TEXTAREA.  The script/app that receives the form input may have some logic in it which kills the process if it sees a SCRIPT tag but in general you can submit whatever text you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the code works fine on WAMP server problem only occurs on LAMP. The app is written by me and there is no logic like you said, in fact the var arrays are all blank even at the entry point of application?

Comment: @Waqar essentially what you said above about the arrays being blank, I understand now

Comment: It's going to be nearly impossible to debug this without more info. Can you put your code up somewhere like http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: You definitely have some security module running on your server that is returning a 403 Forbidden error when a script tag is input.  You get the same error if you enter an SQL statement.  I would put some more effort into checking for mod_security and Suhosin.

Comment: I've dropped an email to the hosting providers, hoping to hear soon from them

Answer (score 1):

This is quite certainly some misguided security mechanism either in your browser, or (more likely) on the server.

As said, check Suhosin out using `phpinfo()`:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

You should see some mention of the word "Suhosin" or "Hardened PHP" in the resulting output.

Also I wouldn't rule out `mod_security` - the errors you say you got when adding the lines disabling it in `.htaccess` might have some other reason. It could for example be configured that it's impossible to turn off through `.htaccess`.

Ask your web host whether they have anything enabled security-wise that might be causing this.

Comment: @Waqar indeed. Can you ask the provider whether they have anything running?

Comment: I've dropped an email to them

Answer (score 0):

Your phpinfo() says that string.strip_tags is registered as a stream filter.  This might be causing your issue.

Also, your filter extension may be configured to strip although that isn't as likely.

Comment: string.strip_tags is also registered on my windows machine (WAMP server) and I don't get an error there! I dont' use php filtering extension, could it still be causing problems?

Comment: Does your WAMP server have the filtering extension?

Comment: Yeah, filters are same in both LAMP and WAMP

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps it would be something to do with your enctype="multipart/form-data" argument in the form declaration... The handlers may be acting differently due to differing mime type handlers... then again I don't see why it would work with <p> tags and return a 404 with <script> tags... this leads me to believe that mod_security is being used with a SecFilterDefaultAction "deny,log,status:404" and a SecFilter "<script" directive...

Comment: the later makes sense. May be they are using the mod_security v2 which does not allow overrides via .htaccess file :/

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits a < p > tag it works as expected.  When the user submits a < script > tag a 404 is returned.  This leads me to believe apache is using mod_security with a configuration similar to:

```
SecFilterDefaultAction "deny,log,status:404"
SecFilter "<script"
```

Comment: Agreed, I dropped an email to the hosting providing, and they said that they are using mod_security v2 which does not support overriding via .htaccess file. They said that they'll ask the administrators to exclude my site from the rules. Thanks for your answer.